# Google Colab don't get the file from GCS Bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory, tpu

I am trying to train a model from this [repo](https://github.com/stevezheng23/xlnet_extension_tf) with TPU which requires all input files and the model directory must use a cloud storage bucket.

I did create a bucket and upload all the files of the model.

But google colab cannot read the path of my bucket. This is the command I run the file:

```
!python run_coqa.py \
--use_tpu=True \
--tpu=TF_MASTER \ # 'grpc://'
--spiece_model_file=/content/xlnet_extension_tf/model/xlnet_cased_L-24_H-1024_A-16/spiece.model \
--model_config_path=gs://my_xlnet_2/xlnet_cased_L-24_H-1024_A-16/xlnet_config.json \
--init_checkpoint=gs://my_xlnet_2/xlnet_cased_L-24_H-1024_A-16/xlnet_model.ckpt \
--task_name=coqa \
--random_seed=100 \
--predict_tag=xxxxx \
--data_dir=/content/xlnet_extension_tf/data \
--output_dir=gs://my_xlnet_2/xlnet_output \
--model_dir=gs://my_xlnet_2/xlnet_output \
--export_dir=gs://my_xlnet_2/xlnet_output \
...
```

Then I got this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://my_xlnet_2/xlnet_output'
```

I can upload file to my bucket with this command, `BUCKET_NAME = 'gs://my_xlnet_2'`:

```
!gsutil mv /content/xlnet_extension_tf/model/xlnet_cased_L-24_H-1024_A-16 $BUCKET_NAME
```

Do you guys know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using the right form of 'slash'? For windows and mac/linux it's different.

Comment: @Landon I use google colab so the path is correct.